# Copy only cells with data from Excel to Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, powerpoint

I have a table on Excel that, depending on the filter applied to it, varies on size (number of rows; the number of columns is always the same).

The table is in range B2:F7 of a sheet called "Retailers".

I would like to write a VBA script that would copy the table to slide 35 of an existing Powerpoint presentation called "Stores". However, because the table varies in size, I would like it, at each time the code is ran, to copy only those rows that have values.

I have tried to do this:

```
Sub Copy Table ()

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Retailers").Range("B2:F7")

'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
```

I am not sure how to paste it to Powerpoint nor to only copy the rows with data.

How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub t()
    Dim copy_range As Range, paste_range As Range
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set copy_range = .Range("A1:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    Set paste_range = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A5")

    copy_range.Copy paste_range
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is, how to choose non blank cells?
You could use dynamic range selection - using End property or even more easily CurrentRegion property. It works like the ctrl+shift+arrows shortcut in normal excel view.